# Task not found KotlinNpmInstall in KotlinMultiplatform Project targeting JS

Tags: kotlin, gradle, npm, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

after trying to add [yarn lock version issue from jetbrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34014) I encountered a strange issue. I have a Multiplatform project currently only targeting the web. When I add a line like `tasks.named("kotlinNpmInstall").configure {` to my web apps build gradle I get a crash

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file '/Frontend/web-app/build.gradle.kts' line: 227
Task with name 'kotlinNpmInstall' not found in project ':web-app'.
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.InterpreterKt$locationAwareExceptionFor$2.invoke(Interpreter.kt:563)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.InterpreterKt.locationAwareExceptionFor(Interpreter.kt:570)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.InterpreterKt.locationAwareExceptionHandlingFor(Interpreter.kt:536)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.InterpreterKt.access$locationAwareExceptionHandlingFor(Interpreter.kt:1)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.handleScriptException(Interpreter.kt:385)
    at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:506)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.evaluateSecondStageOf(Interpreter.kt:431)
    at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.eval(Interpreter.kt:506)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.kt:200)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator.evaluate(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:113)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:51)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:36)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:723)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:69)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:226)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:164)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with name 'kotlinNpmInstall' not found in project ':web-app'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.named(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.named(DefaultTaskCollection.java:112)
    at Build_gradle.<init>(build.gradle.kts:227)
    ... 150 more
```

When I remove this and run `./gradlew tasks` I of course have `kotlinNpmInstall` listed and everything works fine, even running the project will actually use the task `kotlinNpmInstall` and work

```
NodeJs tasks
------------
jsPackageJson - Create package.json file for compilation 'main' (target js (js))
jsTestPackageJson - Create package.json file for compilation 'test' (target js (js))
kotlinNodeJsSetup - Download and install a local node/npm version
kotlinNpmCachesSetup - Setup file hasher for caches
kotlinNpmInstall - Find, download and link NPM dependencies and projects
kotlinYarnSetup - Download and install a local yarn version
```

I have two warnings

```
Kotlin language settings property 'experimentalAnnotationsInUse' is deprecated and will be removed in next major releases. Please, use 'optInAnnotationsInUse' instead.

AND 

Unsupported Kotlin plugin version.
```

Using Kotlin 1.5.30 target JS(IR)

EDIT:

My gradle setup

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpackConfig.Mode.DEVELOPMENT
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpackConfig.Mode.PRODUCTION

plugins {
    kotlin("js")
    id("org.gradlewebtools.minify") version Versions.gradleMinify
}

//https://gist.github.com/CameronProbert/85b7d60fa9572d93566f5c5ee62441e0
/**
 * The build type argument
 *
 * Supports `DEBUG` and `RELEASE`
 * Defaults to `DEBUG` if not specified
 */
val buildModeArg = (project.findProperty("buildMode") as String?)?.toUpperCase()
// Convert the argument to the Webpack Build Mode
val buildMode = when (buildModeArg) {
    null, "DEBUG" -> DEVELOPMENT
    "RELEASE" -> PRODUCTION
    else -> throw Exception("Invalid buildMode: '$buildModeArg'. Expected 'DEBUG' or 'RELEASE'.")
}

/**
 * The environment to target for target database, analytics, etc...
 *
 * Supports `DEV`, 'STAGING' and `PROD`
 * Defaults to `DEV` if not specified
 */
val envTargetArg = (project.findProperty("envTarget") as String?)?.toUpperCase()
val envTarget = when (envTargetArg) {
    "STAGING", "PROD", "DEV" -> envTargetArg
    null -> "DEV"
    else -> throw Exception("Invalid envTarget: '$envTargetArg'. Expected 'DEV', 'STAGING' or 'PROD'.")
}

logger.lifecycle("Building with buildMode = $buildMode and envTarget = $envTarget")

group = "com.test.example"
version = "0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-js-wrappers")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":common:main"))
    implementation(project(":common:auth"))
    implementation(project(":common:profile"))
    implementation(project(":common:proposals"))
    implementation(project(":common:jobs"))
    implementation(project(":common:root"))
    implementation(project(":common:data"))
    implementation(project(":common:utils"))
    implementation(project(":common:di"))

    //  implementation(npm("firebase", "8.10.0"))
    with(Deps.KotlinJSWrappers) {
        implementation(enforcedPlatform(bom))
        implementation(react)
        implementation(reactDom)
        implementation(styled)
        implementation(popper)
    }

    implementation(npm("file-loader", "6.2.0"))

    implementation(npm("@heroicons/react", "1.0.0"))
    implementation(npm("@headlessui/react", "1.4.1"))
    implementation(npm("@tippyjs/react", "4.2.5"))
    implementation(npm("react-lottie-player", "1.4.1"))
    implementation(npm("react-responsive", "8.2.0"))
    implementation(npm("react-hook-form", "7.17.1"))
    implementation(npm("react-i18next", "11.12.0"))
    implementation(npm("i18next", "21.3.3"))
    implementation(npm("i18next-browser-languagedetector", "6.1.2"))
    implementation(npm("i18next-http-backend", "1.3.1"))

    implementation(npm("firebase", "8.10.0"))

    implementation(npm("postcss", Versions.postcss))
    implementation(npm("postcss-loader", Versions.postcssLoader))
    implementation(npm("autoprefixer", Versions.autoprefixer))
    implementation(npm("tailwindcss", Versions.tailwind))

    //implementation(Deps.Kotlinx.time)

    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
    implementation(Deps.Koin.core)
    implementation(Deps.Log.kermit)

    implementation(Deps.Firebase.kmpAuth)

    implementation(Deps.Decompose.decompose)
    implementation(Deps.MVIKotlin.mvikotlin)
    implementation(Deps.MVIKotlin.mvikotlinExtensionsCoroutines)
    implementation(Deps.MVIKotlin.mvikotlinMain)
    implementation(Deps.MVIKotlin.mvikotlinLogging)

    implementation(Deps.Ktor.auth)
    implementation(Deps.Ktor.clientJson)
    implementation(Deps.Ktor.clientCore)
    implementation(Deps.Ktor.clientLogging)
    implementation(Deps.Ktor.clientSerialization)

    implementation(Deps.TouchLab.stately)
    implementation(Deps.IceRoko.parcelize)
    implementation(Deps.Kotlinx.serializationJson)
    implementation(Deps.Kotlinx.coroutinesCore)
}


kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            testTask {
//                useKarma {
//                    useChromeHeadless()
//                }
            }
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true

                mode = buildMode

                // stop default export of config object in Webpack code because we do it in envConfig.js webpack extension
                export = false
            }

            // from https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-js-react-accessing-configuring-environment-variables/16906/9

            // Set the webpack variables for the build task (webpackTask - for compiling your code to run elsewhere) and
            // the run task (runTask - for running your code locally)
            val envTargetWebpackArgs = listOf("--env", "envTarget=$envTarget")
            webpackTask { args.plusAssign(envTargetWebpackArgs) }
            runTask { args.plusAssign(envTargetWebpackArgs) }
        }

        binaries.executable()
    }
}


val copyTailwindConfig = tasks.register<Copy>("copyTailwindConfig") {
    from("./tailwind.config.js")
    into("${rootProject.buildDir}/js/packages/${rootProject.name}-${project.name}")

    dependsOn(":kotlinNpmInstall")
}

val copyPostcssConfig = tasks.register<Copy>("copyPostcssConfig") {
    from("./postcss.config.js")
    into("${rootProject.buildDir}/js/packages/${rootProject.name}-${project.name}")

    dependsOn(":kotlinNpmInstall")
}

tasks.named("compileKotlinJs") {
    dependsOn(copyTailwindConfig)
    dependsOn(copyPostcssConfig)
}


val jsMinify by tasks.creating(org.gradlewebtools.minify.JsMinifyTask::class.java) {
    dependsOn("browserProductionWebpack")

    srcDir = project.buildDir / "distributions"
    dstDir = project.buildDir / "distributions-minified"

    options {
        compilationLevel = com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
        env = com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerOptions.Environment.BROWSER
    }
}

operator fun File.div(childName: String) = File(this, childName)

// https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48273
rootProject.plugins.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.nodejs.NodeJsRootPlugin::class.java) {
    rootProject.the<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.nodejs.NodeJsRootExtension>().versions.apply {
        webpack.version = "5.59.0"
        webpackCli.version = "4.9.1"
        webpackDevServer.version = "4.3.1"
    }
}

tasks.register("stage") {
    dependsOn("build")
}
```

EDIT: Adding more gradle config

My root build.gradle

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }

    plugins.apply("com.github.ben-manes.versions")


    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.npm.tasks.KotlinNpmInstallTask> {
        args += "--ignore-scripts"
    }
}
```

My BuildSrc build.gradle

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()

    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Deps.Gradle.compose)
    implementation(Deps.Gradle.kotlin)
    implementation(Deps.Gradle.kotlinSerialization)
    implementation(Deps.Gradle.tools)
    // implementation(Deps.Squareup.SQLDelight.gradlePlugin)
    implementation(Deps.Extras.gradleVersions)
    implementation( Deps.Firebase.gradlePlugin)
}

kotlin {
    // Add Deps to compilation, so it will become available in main project
    sourceSets.getByName("main").kotlin.srcDir("buildSrc/src/main/kotlin")
}
```